# How can I copy all files in one tree to another tree except those matching a pattern?

Tags: bash, find, cp

I have a directory tree under ./src/

I have another matching directory tree under ./work/

I'm trying to copy all the files in src to work, while keeping the directory structure and excluding all files that end in .java.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
find src -type f ! -iname *.java -exec cp {} work \;
```

This almost works, but all the files are put into the top level under work, instead of into the correct place in the directory tree.

How can I do this? (using bash on Mac OS X 10.9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tar cCf /source/path - --exclude "*.java" . | tar xCf /target/path -`

Comment: That's some creative thinking! Worked like a charm, and I'd have never though to use tar.

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -a --exclude='*.java' src/ work/
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `{}` multiple times.
So:

```
find src -type f ! -iname '*.java' -exec cp {} work/{} \;
```

will try and preserve path (and fail, because the directory probably doesn't exist. - however you could probably do:

```
-exec mkdir -p `dirname {}` \;
```

However, for what you're doing, you *probably* want to use tar:

```
find src -type f ! -iname '*.java' | xargs tar cvf - | ( cd work && tar xvf - )
```

Comment: Just tried running it. Seems to work, assuming you have both 'src' and 'work' in the cwd. (And the 'find' returns some files)
`

Comment: Typo on my part - mea culpa.